# Upload File with Meta-Data (`multipart/form-data`) to ColdFusion 11 REST Service

Tags: rest, file-upload, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

How do you access meta-data (form data) sent with a file upload (using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) in a ColdFusion 11 REST Service?

Mocking up a simple service:

```
component
  restpath = "test"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function upload(
    required numeric id       restargsource = "Path",
    required any     document restargsource = "Form",
    required string  title    restargsource = "Form"
  )
    httpmethod = "POST"
    restpath   = "{id}/"
    produces   = "application/json"
  {
    if ( FileExists( document ) )
      restSetResponse({
        "status"  = 201,
        "content" = {
          "id"    = id,
          "title" = title,
          "size"  = GetFileInfo( document ).size
        }
      });
    else
      restSetResponse({
        "status"  = 400,
        "content" = "Nothing uploaded"
      });
  }
}
```

and a simple HTML file to test it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post"
      action="http://localhost/rest/TestService/test/1/"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title"    value="File Title" /><br />
<input type="file" name="document" /><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the service returns a `500` HTTP status code and the JSON response:

```
{"Message":"The DOCUMENT parameter to the upload function is required but was not passed in."}
```

Checking the HTTP request headers shows that both fields were passed in but the service is not receiving them.

Commenting out the `enctype` attribute within the HTML form (so it uses the default encoding of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) then the service returns a `400` HTTP status code and the response `Nothing uploaded`.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be thoroughly confusing the request data populates the `FORM` variable but, even though the function arguments state `restargsource="form"`, the value is not passed on to the REST service as its argument when the `enctype` is anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This is confirmed in Adobe's [Getting started with RESTful web services in ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html) article:

> **Form parameters:**
>
> In many scenarios, you must process data that you enter in the form in a REST service. You can use this data to make a new entry ( `POST` ) or update an existing record ( `PUT` ) in the database. If you use form fields, set `restargsource` to `form` . This extracts the data present in the request and makes it available for further processing. Also, you must set the content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when sending data as form fields.

However, it can be solved by changing the arguments which would use `restargsource="form"` to be parameters explicitly scoped within the `form` variable.

So, the modifying the service like this:

```
component
  restpath = "test"
  rest     = true
{
  remote void function upload(
    required numeric id       restargsource = "Path"
  )
    httpmethod = "POST"
    restpath   = "{id}/"
    produces   = "application/json"
  {
    param name="form.document" type="string";
    param name="form.title"    type="string";

    if ( FileExists( form.document ) )
      restSetResponse({
        "status"  = 201,
        "content" = {
          "id"    = id,
          "title" = form.title,
          "size"  = GetFileInfo( form.document ).size
        }
      });
    else
      restSetResponse({
        "status"  = 400,
        "content" = "Nothing uploaded"
      });
  }
}
```